# How to create TextView,ImageView and Relative Layout Programmatically

Tags: android

I am new born in android. I created a xml file but now i want to create all my layout programmatically. I see many examples but i couldn't find my solution.

I want below these component programmatically same :-

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bag" />


        <TextView
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="bugAndLuggage"
            android:text="@string/bug_luggage"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why do you want to create dynamically ? you can inflate the same view ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(context);
//set Relative Layout Parameter using 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
```

//Create ImageView in the same manner

```
ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
```

// add layout parameters to each view with different options as you //have set it in the xml

```
TextView textView=new TextView(context);
relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

**UPDATE**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259802/2793134

Comment: how to set textview `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"` these attribute.

Answer (score -1):

instead of creating Dynamic views you can use layout inflater to inflate your view.
so you can use the same xml layout file for inflating the views.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bag" />


    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick="bugAndLuggage"
        android:text="@string/bug_luggage"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and in code

```
   View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ID, null);
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.srelative_layout_id);
   TextView tv= (TextView)v.findViewBytId(R.id.id_of_text_view);
```